# How to figure out property config for using local unix server as SMTP server

Tags: java, spring, smtp

How to figure out property config for using local unix server as SMTP server

Since GMAIl and other SMTP servers do not allow changing "FROM" email address other than the one authenticated in configuration, I need to use hosting linux server as SMTP server.

What proprty configuration I will require and how to find their values?

Can someone explain in context to bean configuration I have for GMAIL?

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
<property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
<property name="port" value="587" />
<property name="username" value="xxxxxx@gmail.com" />
<property name="password" value="xyxyxyxyx" />

<property name="javaMailProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
        <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I think I got the answer (if this could help somebody); found it working for me

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
   <property name="host" value="localhost" />
   <property name="port" value="25" />
</bean>
```